# Java network stack security?

Tags: java, security, java-security

I got into another argument with my friend a while ago. He claims that Java is extremely insecure due to the network stack it uses. He says that weather or not you use the network, this network stack is open and running. And at anytime you have a Java application running, somebody can hijack the JVM through the network stack and take control of your computer. Does any of this have truth to it? Sorry if this isn't a "real" question or is limited on details, but that is all he told me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the jvm security, not about programming. Also, too broad. There is a dedicated security stack exchange, if you have a more specific claim you want to see answered to.

Comment: Your friend sounds confused, but it's pretty difficult to respond to such an unspecific claim, especially in the SO question / answer format.

Comment: Nonsense at its best and off topic. Prove him wrong and start a Java program and then run netstat or tcpview

Comment: "Java is extremely insecure due to the network stack it uses" -- Pure nonsense. "this network stack is open and running" -- Even more nonsense. - If at all, your friend may be incorrectly referring to JMX remote monitoring which would allow remote control of a JVM; but this has to be enabled explicitly and does not pose an issue if not enabled.

Comment: You suspect it's not a real (ie welcome) question but yet you post it anyway? Why? It's not as if you're a new user.

Comment: @HannoBinder "In the Java SE 6 platform, it is no longer necessary to set this system property. Any application that is started on the Java SE 6 platform will support the Attach API, and so will automatically be made available for local monitoring and management when needed." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

Comment: I forgot about the security stack exchange. He seems very bias over this so I wasn't sure how to ask it on here.

Comment: @chris13524 correct, *local* monitoring is enabled by default; monitoring via network must still be enabled explicitly.

Comment: I just told him about the JMX remote thing and said that you guys said it was nonsense. He said it was the JVM it's self and you are all Java lovers and are not aware of Java's insecurities. I think it's nonsense, but it's bugging me.

Comment: Does he have a source (e.g. on the internet) confirming his claim?

Comment: @HannoBinder I doubt it, but I can ask.

Comment: On another note, don't let things like that bug you. We all know people who insist on things we *know* are incorrect. Look at all those conspiracy theories around. It's usually close to impossible to convince them and really not worth the effort. Accept his opinion as *his* opinion, then go and have a drink together.

Comment: He doesn't have a source. I tried the netstat thing, nothing showed up, but he says that on Linux, if you run the command `iptools -b <javapath>`, it will show you all 9 ports Java keeps open. I don't have access to my Linux machine though. I try not to let it bug me, but he insists on the hundreds of issues Oracle fixes each week (which I know the reason of), and how terrible the JVM is...even though he writes Android apps.

Comment: Hehe, so Windows is in the conspiracy too, collaborating with the JVM to hide its evil security flaws? :o)

Comment: Yeah, Linux all the way! :D

Comment: Good thing Android is based on Linux, so it will never leak any private information to companies all over the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this [insert your favorite curse here] bugs me as much as it does you I created a short test program:

```
public class Shullbit {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    while( true )  {
      System.out.println( "Still not convinced ?!?" );
      try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      }
      catch( Exception e ) {
        //
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After start this program just sits there and waits. This leaves us enough time to search for open ports.
I ran the code on Ubuntu 14.04 with this java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

When I run the program with `java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote Shullbit` I can see that a port was opened:

```
sudo netstat -anop | grep java
tcp6       0      0 :::56066                :::*                    LISTEN      18797/java       off (0.00/0/0)
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     30209    18797/java
```

But this was expected because we told Java to do so. And this port can by default only be used locally and can be secured by SSL, passwords or client certificates.

When I run the same program with just `java Shullbit` there are no open ports:

```
sudo netstat -anop | grep java  | wc -l
0
```

So tell your friend to either go back to work or school ;-)